# Extrct comm rows from two dataframes based on muilt identifier use R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes that looks like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, loc = 100:104, ft = 2:6)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 2:6, loc = c(101:104,105), ft = 7:11)
```

I want to get two dataframes based on comm "id" and "loc" for df1 and df2,respectively. looks like :

```
df1.1
  id loc ft
2  2 101  3
3  3 102  4
4  4 103  5
5  5 104  6
df2.1
  id loc ft
1  2 101  7
2  3 102  8
3  4 103  9
4  5 104 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an inner join with the `ft` column removed from the other data frame.

```
df1.1 <- merge(df1, df2[-3], by = c("id", "loc"))
df1.1
  id loc ft
1  2 101  3
2  3 102  4
3  4 103  5
4  5 104  6

df2.1 <- merge(df2, df1[-3], by = c("id", "loc"))
df2.1
  id loc ft
1  2 101  7
2  3 102  8
3  4 103  9
4  5 104 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without `merge()`:

```
df1[df1$id %in% df2$id & df1$loc %in% df2$loc,]
#   id loc ft
#1:  2 101  3
#2:  3 102  4
#3:  4 103  5
#4:  5 104  6

df2[df2$id %in% df1$id & df2$loc %in% df1$loc,]
#   id loc ft
#1:  2 101  7
#2:  3 102  8
#3:  4 103  9
#4:  5 104 10
```

Comment: Good option plus one.